# Storekit - Configure a subscription status URL using Firebase functions

Tags: firebase, app-store-connect, google-cloud-functions, storekit

I'm trying to use Firebase functions as our server. Here's the function I'm using. It works fine when I trigger it over HTTP

```
exports.subscriptions = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  // Send 200 code to the server indicate to that you are done!
  response.send(200);

});
```

Apple Says:

> The App Store will deliver JSON objects via an HTTP POST to your
>   server for the key subscription

But so far I didn't get any notification from Apple server.

Any suggestions would be great?

**I checked the logs in the console and it seems that I have started receiving notifications from Apple server.**

Answer (score 0):

well you're only saying to apple that you're done, if you add `console.log(req.body)` to your function it should give you some data in the logs :)

Comment: Does Firebase provide a builtin URL that receives notifications from Apple in the format Apple sends? Or do we have to implement it ourselves as Jad has done?

Comment: Firebase provides a url for every function, here is the standard template:
https://us-central1-<insert project name here>.cloudfunctions.net/<insert function name here, in @jad's case this is subscriptions>
so the final url would be for a project called applesubscription
https://us-central1-applesubscription.cloudfunctions.net/subscription